# Null Pointer Exception on retrieving multiple select values in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

Using JSP, in my HTML, I have a form that I submit to another page. The form has a select list that has multiple elements. Before submitting the form, In java script, I make sure that all elements in the list are selected. Then I submit the form to the next page. In the next page, I assign selected values in the list to a java array. When I try to display the size of the array or any value in that array, I get Null Pointer Exception.

Here's my form with the list:

```
<form name="inputGenesForm" id="test" method="POST" ACTION="result.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">          
    <div style=" position:absolute;top:6%;left:39%;">
    ...
    ...
    <select id="inputSet2" multiple="multiple" style="position:absolute; top: 93px; left: 270px; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
```

In result.jsp,

```
<body background="image/geneBG.jpg">
<%       
    String [] selectedGenes= request.getParameterValues("inputSet2");
%>

<script>    
    alert(<%=selectedGenes.length%>);
</script>
```

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Error on submitting form to result.jsp:

```
type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.getParameterValues() is not working in combination with "enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1):

in the results.jsp file alert this instead:

```
alert(<%=request.getParameterValues("inputSet2")%>);
```

and remove this line:

```
String [] selectedGenes= request.getParameterValues("inputSet2");
```

to determine for a fact that the inputSet2 field is null.

Also, to be able to see what is sent to the results page change your form post method to get:

```
<form name="inputGenesForm" id="test" method="get" action="result.jsp">
```

If you were not able to narrow down to the problem below is a little test that I did and got to work.

form.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing MultiSelect</title>
<script>
var validate= function() {
   if(document.forms.form1.select2.selectedIndex == -1) {
        alert("Please select one or more options");
        return false;
   }
   return true;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="result.jsp">
      <select name="select2" size="3" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
        <option value="4">four</option>
        <option value="5">five</option>
        <option value="6">six</option>
        <option value="7">seven</option>
        <option value="8">eight</option>
        <option value="9">nine</option>
        <option value="10">ten</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" tabindex="2" onclick="return validate()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

result.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Results Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>These Are Your Results</h1>
<p>
<% String [] selectedGenes = request.getParameterValues("select2");
   for (String selectedGene : selectedGenes)
        out.println(selectedGene + "<br>");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I selected the first three options and the get url was

```
result.jsp?select2=1&select2=2&select2=3&Submit=Submit
```

Comment: aha. The value is null. Why? What mistake did I make?

Comment: well from what I see your code should have worked, so let's keep working backwards to debug. switch that alert now to request.getParameter("inputSet2");

Comment: sounds like something is up with how the form is being posted? try this instead in your form page so you can see exactly what is getting sent to results.jsp: <form name="inputGenesForm" id="test" method="get" action="result.jsp">

Comment: Lucas Merencia is right, you are missing the name attribute in your selected. I completely missed that, but the above would have shown that inputSet2 wasn't coming over.

Comment: I added the name, but it still gives null.

Comment: did you change the form's post method to get? if so, what was the url that came over to request.jsp?

Comment: it is result.jsp?text=&inputQueryList=YER087W&Submit2=Submit

Comment: YER087W is the value selected

Comment: so then `String [] selectedGenes= request.getParameterValues("inputSet2");` should actually be `String [] selectedGenes= request.getParameterValues("inputQueryList");` if what you are trying to get is the value YER087W

Comment: No, I changed it already to : request.getParameterValues("inputQueryList");
but this still gives me null

Answer (score 1):

Try add the name attribute in select

```
<select name="inputSet2" ...>
```

" Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form. " http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp

Comment: I added the name, but it still gives null.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you check this for a null value first ?

```
selectedGenes.length
```

The doc for [getParameterValues()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> Returns an array of String objects containing all of the values the
>   given request parameter has, or *null if the parameter does not exist*.

(my emphasis)

Comment: I checked if(selectedGenes==null)
        alert("null!");
But I got the same error!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved with:

```
String [] selectedGenes = request.getParameterValues("select2[]");
```